# How can I compare INStartCallContactResolutionResult objects for unit testing?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, sirikit

I'm trying to unit test my Intent Handler class for INStartCallIntent, but I'm having trouble comparing the result objects for contact resolution.

For example, given a basic handler for INStartCallIntent:

```swift
import Intents

class StartCallHandler: NSObject, INStartCallIntentHandling {
        func resolveContacts(for intent: INStartCallIntent, with completion: @escaping ([INStartCallContactResolutionResult]) -> Void) {
        guard let contacts = intent.contacts, !contacts.isEmpty, let person = contacts.first else {
            completion([.needsValue()])
            return
        }
        
        guard contacts.count == 1 else {
            completion([.unsupported(forReason: .multipleContactsUnsupported)])
            return
        }

        let matchingContacts = [person] // matching logic here
        switch matchingContacts.count {
        case 2  ... Int.max:
            // We need Siri's help to ask user to pick one from the matches.
            completion([.disambiguation(with: matchingContacts)])
        case 1:
            // We have exactly one matching contact
            completion([.success(with: person)])
        default:
            completion([.unsupported(forReason: .noContactFound)])
        }
    }
}
```

If I create a simple unit test, I'm unable to to compare the INStartCallContactResolutionResult objects:

```swift
func testResolveContacts() {
    let person = INPerson(personHandle: INPersonHandle(value: nil, type: .unknown), nameComponents: nil, displayName: "Steve Jobs", image: nil, contactIdentifier: nil, customIdentifier: nil)
    let intent = INStartCallIntent(audioRoute: .unknown, destinationType: .unknown, contacts: [person], recordTypeForRedialing: .unknown, callCapability: .audioCall)
    let handler = StartCallHandler()
        
    handler.resolveContacts(for: intent) { result in
        XCTAssertEqual(result.count, 1)
        guard let firstResult = result.first else { return XCTFail() }
        
        let expectedPerson = INPerson(personHandle: INPersonHandle(value: nil, type: .unknown), nameComponents: nil, displayName: "Steve Jobs", image: nil, contactIdentifier: nil, customIdentifier: nil)
        let expectedResult = INStartCallContactResolutionResult(.success(with: expectedPerson))
        XCTAssertEqual(firstResult, expectedResult)
    }
}
```

The XCTAssertEqual fails with this message:

> XCTAssertEqual failed: ("<INStartCallContactResolutionResult:
> 0x600002109310> {
> resolutionResultCode = Success;
> resolvedValue = <INPerson: 0x600002c7b780> {
> displayName = Steve Jobs;
> contactIdentifier = ;
> nameComponents = ;
> image = ;
> customIdentifier = ;
> relationship = ;
> siriMatches = ;
> personHandle = <INPersonHandle: 0x600000d78960> {
> value = ;
> type = Unknown;
> label = ;
> };
> };
> disambiguationItems = ;
> itemToConfirm = ;
> unsupportedReason = 0; }") is not equal to ("<INStartCallContactResolutionResult: 0x6000021092c0> {
> resolutionResultCode = Success;
> resolvedValue = <INPerson: 0x600002c7b900> {
> displayName = Steve Jobs;
> contactIdentifier = ;
> nameComponents = ;
> image = ;
> customIdentifier = ;
> relationship = ;
> siriMatches = ;
> personHandle = <INPersonHandle: 0x600000d78d80> {
> value = ;
> type = Unknown;
> label = ;
> };
> };
> disambiguationItems = ;
> itemToConfirm = ;
> unsupportedReason = 0; }")

So even though the two objects have identical properties, the XCTAssertEqual fails presumably because there is no equality function implemented on Apple's end.

This makes it pretty much impossible to test this function as a result. Has anyone been able to accomplish this some other way?

Comment: Something doesn't add up, in the code you provided `expected` is an instance of `INPerson`, however the error message says that two `INStartCallContactResolutionResult` were compared. Something seems to be outdated here, either the code, or the failure message.

Comment: You're right. My example code is wrong. The expected should be an `INStartCallContactResolutionResult` object, not INPerson. I'll update it.

Comment: I think you need to implement the conformance to Equatable yourself.

Comment: I tried that but there is a compilation error: `Conformance of 'INStartCallContactResolutionResult' to protocol 'Equatable' was already stated in the type's module 'Intents'`. Also, the example code should be updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing here is putting the contact resolver logic in a separate helper class and wrapping the `INStartCallContactResolutionResult` class into a custom enum that essentially just maps it 1:1.

```swift
public enum PersonResolverUnsupportedReason {
    case startCallContactUnsupportedReason(INStartCallContactUnsupportedReason)
}

public enum PersonResolverResult {
    case success(INPerson)
    case disambiguation([INPerson])
    case needsValue
    case unsupported
    case unsupportedWithReason(PersonResolverUnsupportedReason)
    case skip
    
    var startCallContactResolutionResult: INStartCallContactResolutionResult {
        switch self {
        case let .success(person):
            return .success(with: person)
        case let .disambiguation(persons):
            return .disambiguation(with: persons)
        case .needsValue:
            return .needsValue()
        case .unsupported:
            return .unsupported()
        case let .unsupportedWithReason(reason):
            switch reason {
            case let .startCallContactUnsupportedReason(startCallReason):
                return .unsupported(forReason: startCallReason)
            }
        case .skip:
            return .notRequired()
        }
    }
}

public protocol PersonResolverProtocol: AnyObject {
    func attemptToResolvePerson(_ person: INPerson, with: @escaping ([PersonResolverResult]) -> Void)
}

public class PersonResolver: PersonResolverProtocol {
    public func attemptToResolvePerson(_ person: INPerson, with completion: @escaping ([PersonResolverResult]) -> Void) {
        let matchingContacts = [person] // matching logic here
        switch matchingContacts.count {
        case 2...Int.max:
            completion([.disambiguation(matchingContacts.map { INPerson(...) })])
        case 1:
            guard let matchingContact = matchingContacts.first else {
                completion([.unsupportedWithReason(.startCallContactUnsupportedReason(.noContactFound))])
                break
            }
            completion([.success(INPerson(...))])
        default:
            // no contacts match
            completion([.unsupportedWithReason(.startCallContactUnsupportedReason(.noContactFound))])
        }
    }
}
```

So now I can:

- Unit test the contact resolver logic better
- Inject this resolver into StartCallHandler
- Re-use the contact resolver class in other intent handler classes if needed.